# relation model between two models: the relational key

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I would like to make a relation between two models User and Task using backbone-relational.
I would like for each Task to get the User model or User attributes.

The relation between the two models is the following:

```
taskModel.creator_id = userModel.id
```

---

```
// TaskModel
var TaskModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    relations: [
        {
            type: 'HasOne',
            key: 'creator_id',
            relatedModel: UserModel
        }
    ],

    urlRoot: 'url_get_tasks'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasOne,
            key: 'user',
            relatedModel: UserModel
        }
    ]
```

`key` attribute store initial data for related model.
You can define [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method in TaskModel to make  `user: {id: 1}` from `creator_id: 1`  on `fetch` or do it on in `initialize`:

```
this.set('user', {id: this.get('creator_id') })
```

Comment: It does not work, anyway looks to this question because the problem is related [Foreign key populated with an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346777/foreign-key-populated-with-an-object)